# MariaDB cannot evaluate SELECT 1 WHERE NULL = NULL;

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm currently in process of learning SQL. I have an example from a book that I'm trying to understand, but MariaDB cannot evaluate it:

```
SELECT 1
WHERE NULL = NULL
UNION
SELECT 0
WHERE NULL <> NULL;
```

This however gives the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NULL = NULL
UNION
SELECT 0
WHERE NULL <> NULL;' at line 2
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT 1;
```

which works. However this doesn't:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE NULL = NULL;
```

I have also tried adding parantheses, but that didn't help much. What am I doing wrong here? This example was to show that comparing NULL with any other value gives "Unknown".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can not use `WHERE` without `FROM`. `SELECT 1 WHERE 1 = 1` will also not work.

To fix your example you could select from a dummy table:

```
SELECT 1
FROM (SELECT 'dummy_value') dummy_table
WHERE NULL = NULL
UNION
SELECT 0
FROM (SELECT 'dummy_value') dummy_table
WHERE NULL <> NULL
```

But a better way to see how MySQL behaves could be

```
SELECT 
    NULL = NULL,
    NULL <> NULL,
    NULL IS NULL,
    NULL IS NOT NULL,
    1 = NULL,
    1 <> NULL,
    1 IS NULL,
    1 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: The _normal_ way to test for null is `col IS NULL` or `col IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Thanks @RickJames - this is more SQL style. So i changed it.

Answer (score 1):

That's the expected behavior, according to [the MariaDB docs on NULLs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/null-values/):

> NULL values cannot be used with most comparison operators. For example, =, >, >=, <=, <, or != cannot be used, as any comparison with a NULL always returns a NULL value, never true (1) or false (0).

Notice that the example on that docs page has the `NULL = NULL` in the column list, not in the where clause, since the column list will return the result of the comparison, and the where clause requires a boolean expression.

Comment: SELECT NULL = NULL; This works like a charm. If it was the boolean expression, WHERE 1 = 1 would work?

Comment: `NULL` can be compared with the `<=>` operator.