# Give a value to a column from joining master table and link table on select query

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have a two master table. Because the relation is many to many, I decide to create link table to create one to many relation.
This is the master table :

**First table**

```
MariaDB [ittresnamuda]> SELECT * FROM tb_item_request;
+---------+-----------+
| ID_TIPE | NAMA_TIPE |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | Login     |
|       2 | Printer   |
|       3 | Monitor   |
|       4 | Computer  |
|       5 | Network   |
|       6 | Lain-lain |
+---------+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**SECOND TABLE**

```
MariaDB [ittresnamuda]> select a.ID_REQUEST, a.CATATAN from tb_requestfix a;
+------------+---------------------------------+
| ID_REQUEST | CATATAN                         |
+------------+---------------------------------+
|          3 | Akan kami cek jaringan tersebut |
|          4 | Iya, go ahead. Appproved        |
|          5 | Sudah di refill                 |
|         28 | Saja                            |
+------------+---------------------------------+
```

4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

**LINK TABLE**

```
MariaDB [ittresnamuda]> select * from tb_link_item_request;
+----+------------+---------+
| ID | id_request | id_item |
+----+------------+---------+
| 16 |          4 |       1 |
| 17 |          4 |       2 |
| 18 |          4 |       3 |
| 19 |          4 |       4 |
| 20 |          4 |       5 |
| 21 |          4 |       6 |
| 26 |          3 |       2 |
| 27 |          3 |       3 |
| 28 |          3 |       4 |
| 29 |          3 |       5 |
| 30 |          5 |       6 |
| 56 |         28 |       2 |
+----+------------+---------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I need to select the table in this format :

```
+------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------+
| ID_REQUEST | CATATAN                         | L | P | M | C | N | LL|
+------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------+
|          3 | Akan kami cek jaringan tersebut |   | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
|          4 | Iya, go ahead. Appproved        | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
|          5 | Sudah di refill                 |   |   | 1 |   |   | 1 |
|         28 | Saja                            |   | 1 |   |   |   |   |
+------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------+

L = Login, P = Printer, M = Monitor, so on, so on
```

As you can see, on `ID_REQUEST =  4` have 6 record on  `tb_link_item_request`. So, There must be have a value = 1 on the table that I need. What I supposed use on query, join, group, is exactly I guess?

Any help it so appreciated.

**UPDATE**, as comment below, it seems impossible to create like that ?
How bout like this :

```
+------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------+
| ID_REQUEST | CATATAN                         | L | P | M | C | N | LL|
+------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------+
|          3 | Akan kami cek jaringan tersebut |   | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
|          4 | Iya, go ahead. Appproved        | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
|          5 | Sudah di refill                 |   |   | 3 |   |   | 6 |
|         28 | Saja                            |   | 2 |   |   |   |   |
+------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------+

L = Login, P = Printer, M = Monitor, so on, so on
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: As far as I know this type of display of table in possible by programming your application as per your display needs. Becoz mysql will return the data as ID_REQUEST, CATATAN, NAMA_TIPE., also duplicate column names are not allowed like in your case you have two columns named as 'L'

Comment: How just return id_item on  | L | P |  M |  C |  N |  LL |

Comment: You can natural join 3 tables and then display in the given format using php but this format is not possible using mysql (as per my knowledge)

Comment: did you want me to post the solution to display the data in html table using php.

Comment: Yes, please. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, the last L must be LL

Comment: Check out the answer. It is as per my understanding of your data. I dont have your tables to check the proper working of code. So do it and let me know in Answer comments.

Comment: You can use `GROUP BY ID_REQUEST, CATATAN` and conditional aggregation to pivot the result. There are many examples on SO how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Please give same name to the columns in the LINK Table w.r.t other two tables i.e. tb_link_item_request (ID,ID_REQUEST,ID_TIPE) then use natural join as:

```
SELECT ID_REQUEST,CATATAN, ID_TIPE 
FROM tb_item_request 
     natural join tb_link_item_request 
     natural join tb_requestfix;
```

Now use PHP to display your data as

```
$query="SELECT ID_REQUEST,CATATAN, ID_TIPE 
        FROM tb_item_request 
        natural join tb_link_item_request 
        natural join tb_requestfix order by ID_REQUEST,ID_TIPE";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
if (!$result)
{
  echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($link));
}
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
 echo '<table>'
  .'<tr>'
   .'<th>ID_REQUEST</th>'
   .'<th>CATATAN</th>'
   .'<th>L</th>'
   .'<th>P</th>'
   .'<th>M</th>'
   .'<th>C</th>'
   .'<th>N</th>'
   .'<th>LL</th>'
  .'</tr>';

  $prevIDReq=null;
  $rowCount=0;    
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    if($prevIDReq!=$row['ID_REQUEST']){
      if($prevIDReq!=null)
      {
         while($rowCount<=6){
           echo '<td></td>';
           $rowCount++
         }
         echo '</tr>';
         $rowCount=0;
      }

      echo "<tr>"
           ."<td>".$row['ID_REQUEST']."</td>"
           ."<td>".$row['CATANTAN']."</td>";

    }

    if($row['ID_TIPE']==1){
      echo '<td>1</td>';
    }

    if($row['ID_TIPE']==2){
      while($rowCount<1){
         echo '<td></td>';
         $rowCount++;  
      }
      echo '<td>1</td>';
    }

    if($row['ID_TIPE']==3){
      while($rowCount<2){
         echo '<td></td>';
         $rowCount++;  
      }
      echo '<td>1</td>';
    }        

    if($row['ID_TIPE']==4){
      while($rowCount<3){
         echo '<td></td>';
         $rowCount++;  
      }
      echo '<td>1</td>';
    }

    if($row['ID_TIPE']==5){
      while($rowCount<4){
         echo '<td></td>';
         $rowCount++;  
      }
      echo '<td>1</td>';
    }

    if($row['ID_TIPE']==6){
      while($rowCount<5){
         echo '<td></td>';
         $rowCount++;  
      }
      echo '<td>1</td>';
    }

    $rowCount++:
  }


  while($rowCount<=6){
           echo '<td></td>';
           $rowCount++
         }

  echo '</tr>'
       .'</table>';
}
```

**UPDATE:** as per updated question you can use `"<td>".$row['ID_TIPE']."</td>"` instead of `'<td>1</td>'` in the above code.

Comment: Little confused on your code, coz i am using codeigniter. I keep struggle. Btw, thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation to create a pivot result:

```
SELECT rf.ID_REQUEST, rf.CATATAN
    , BIT_OR(lir.id_item <=> 1) OR NULL AS Login
    , BIT_OR(lir.id_item <=> 2) OR NULL AS Printer
    -- and so on
FROM tb_requestfix rf
LEFT JOIN tb_link_item_request lir ON lir.id_request = rf.ID_REQUEST
GROUP BY rf.ID_REQUEST, rf.CATATAN
```

Result:

```
| ID_REQUEST |                         CATATAN |  Login | Printer |
|------------|---------------------------------|--------|---------|
|          3 | Akan kami cek jaringan tersebut | (null) |       1 |
|          4 | Iya, go ahead. Appproved        |      1 |       1 |
|          5 | Sudah di refill                 | (null) |  (null) |
|         28 | Saja                            | (null) |       1 |
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/661b6a/1)

Use data from `tb_item_request` table, to construct that query in PHP.

You can use `SUM()`, `BIT_OR()`, `GROUP_CONCAT()` or what ever best meets your requirement.

Comment: You rock man, I Just knew the operand '<=>' and BIT_OR. Thanks

Comment: I learned about `<=>` today on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36226019/mariadb-cannot-evaluate-select-1-where-null-null) :-)